# Async JavaScript and I/O

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, asynchronous-javascript

Having just discovered async JavaScript, I have been trying to conceptualize where it makes sense to use it: When about to tackle a problem, I'd like to be able to say from the start: "This is a problem where I should use async JavaScript!", and of course also the opposite.

My first thought was to start (slowly) converting *everything* to async for better interleave between functions. Then I realized there's tremendous overkill in such a strategy. There are plenty of functions that don't need to be asynchronous, like

```
var add = (a,b) => { return a+b;}
```

So now I'm thinking that conceptually, async JavaScript exists primarily for better I/O handling. The only other realm I can think it could be applicable to would be for long running scripts so as to not block JavaScript's single thread.

Anything/anywhere else where I should say "This is a job for async!"?

Comment: JS async is not async in the traditional sense, in that it's still single-threaded and expensive computations still block the single thread. In something known as the event loop, "asynchronous" computations are just deferred for later after the other synchronous computations are done. Async is basically only used for IO computations that have a non-computational delay to them (e.g. having a delay, reading a file, making a web request, etc.)

Comment: Making non-async code async buys you nothing as all javascript code runs on a single main thread. When a function is async such as `fetch()` or `setTimeout()` etc. you have no choice but to use async. In all other cases you don't need to use async. If you have CPU intensive code (not regular for/while loops but things like 3D rendering or mp4 encoding) then look at web workers in the browser or worker threads in node.js to run your code in another thread. The interface between web worker/worker thread and the main thread is async so again you would be forced to use async...

Comment: ... so basically only use async if you are forced to use async

Comment: @Aplet123: *JS async is not async in the traditional sense* On the contrary, it's very common. Async in other languages is same as in js. Myriads of frameworks based on libuv, async/await in .net, asyncio in python, futures in swift. It's the same set of ideas and programming model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript you can only really benefit from `async` if you plan to use an API that itself is asynchronous in nature, i.e. which can do some non-JavaScript task "under the hood" and then put a job (event) on a JavaScript job (event) queue. This job can be a callback or promise resolution.

Some examples of such APIs are:

- Scheduled: [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout), [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)
- Deferred:  [`queueMicrotask`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/queueMicrotask)
- HTTP request: [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch)
- Paint cycle:  [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)
- Another thread: [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)
- Local database: [indexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API)
- ...Any other asynchronous (possibly promise based) API: like [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios), [mongodb](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/quick-start), ...and many other well-known APIs

On top of that, you should really only need `async` if your function uses [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await). An `async` function that doesn't use `await` doesn't make much sense. Even when an `await`-less function would return a promise, then still it does not need to be declared `async`.

On the other hand, if you use some asynchronous behaviour of an API, then it is useful to promisify that API if it does not (yet) expose a promise-based API. As an example, here is a common line of code to promisify `setTimeout`:

```
const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
```

...so now in an `async` function you can introduce a "pause" of 100 milliseconds with:

```
await delay(100);
```

If you are using promises, and find your code has `.then` chains, then that is a good use case for converting to the `async`/`await` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

There are several usecases to make use of async logic in javascript. A common example is performing http requests. As you already pointed out, you do not want to block the scripts execution when waiting on server responses or user inputs.

JavaScript apps make strongly use of the so called promise. A promise will emit an event once it has been resolved or rejected. Another possibility is via callback function:

```js
console.log(1)
const wait = function () {
  return setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(3)
  }, 50)
}
wait()
console.log(2)
```

Example using a promise:

```js
console.log(1)
const wait = function() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve()
    }, 50)
  })
}
wait().then(() => console.log(3))
console.log(2)
```

Hope this clarifies somehow.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise